# Q: Android Dev - Enable a Manifest-Disabled Broadcast-Receiver from Activity

Tags: java, android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest

I have a BroadcastReceiver which is registered in my Manifest file as "Disabled"..
It listens for a System-based Broadcast, and then fires.. but I don't want my BroadcastReceiver to actually be Enabled and Listening until I tell it to (for example, a user-set Preference within my app which makes it Enabled)..
From what i've gathered by searching, I've found the following 2 things that might work:

```
Context.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver
        (LocationReceiver.class, 
            "android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED");
```

and

```
setComponentEnabledSetting
    (LocationReceiver.class, 
        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, 
            0);
```

But neither of them are working..
For the first one, it says "the non-static method getApplicationContext cannot be referenced from a static context, and the second one I think I may just not be referencing the first argument correctly (ComponentName).

Can anybody give me some insight?
Thanks!

Comment: For the first option, drop the Class name (which will make it non-static). Eg.:   getApplicationContext()... instead of Context.getApplicationContext() ...

Comment: I tried what you said .. `getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(LocationReceiver.class, "android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED");` but now the entire argument/s are underlined in red.. Hovering it says this......  registerReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver, android.content.IntentFilter) in Context cannot be applied to .... yada yada.

Answer (score 0):

Try this hope it will work

```
pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP)
```

Comment: I tried this, but still not working.. For the Receiver part, it says its the wrong Argument, and has to be referenced a a ComponentName or something:

    `PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();`
    
    `packageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(LocationReceiver.class, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, 0);`